# EJB @Asynchronous does not work in same class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb

I've the following situation:

[image]

I wish the "methodB" was executed 10 times paralleling. But it only happening when the "methodB" is called from another bean.

Why the annotation "@Asynchronous" does not work when the method is called from another method in the same class?

Thanks.

Comment: Why screenshot of code instead of code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It only works for methods call via a client proxy, for example a `@Local` or `@Remote` interface. This is described in the EJB 3.1 specs (section 4.5 - 4.5.1):

> A session bean can expose methods with asynchronous **client** invocation semantics
>
> ...
>
> The @Asynchronous annotation is used to designate which business methods are asynchronous.
>
> ...
>
> Asynchronous method invocation semantics only apply to the no-interface, Local business, and Remote business **client views**.

Comment: Knowing this, I resolved the problem as follows: @EJB FooLocal bean; bean.methodB(); Thank you very much.

Comment: Your answer is not entirely correct. The section you quote **does not** mandate call going through a remote or local interface. Instead it says that calls need to go via a `view`, which is the EJB terminology for a proxy. If you call the method from within the same EJB, it will go via the implicit `this` parameter, which cannot be intercepted and thus it won't work.

Comment: @RafaelOrágio you do not need the interface. `@EJB Foo bean; bean.methodB();` will work too. See http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/how_to_self_invoke_ejb

Comment: It's true @Arjan Tijms. Thanks!

Comment: but methodB() should be public :)