# @Inject not working EJB calls its own method

Tags: jboss7.x, cdi, ejb-3.1

Platform: JBoss AS 7.1.1.

I have a stateless bean method that needs to call another method of the same bean but has to go through the EJB container.

```
@Stateless
public class OrderManager {
    @Resource
    SessionContext ctx;
    @Inject
    MailUtil mm;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Test");

    public void method1() {
        if (mm == null) {
            logger.info("MailUtil is null");
        }

        ctx.getBusinessObject(OrderManager.class).method2();
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public void method2() {
        if (mm == null) {
            logger.info("MailUtil is null");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the injected variable mm is null within method2(). While, within method1(), a properly injected mm variable exists.

Is this a defect in JBOss, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried injecting the object directly instead of using SessionContext.getBusinessObject?

Comment: Yes, I tried injecting using @EJB. Same result.

Comment: May [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12198983/ejb-asynchronous-does-not-work-in-same-class) help.

Comment: Jin, I am aware of that issue you pointed at. My code is already using the EJB proxy to call method2(). Asynchronous behavior is working just fine. The core issue of this question is that the injection is not happening for method2(). That happens even if I remove @Asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened for me using WebSphere 8.5.5.5. The self injected bean had null in *its* injected beans.

The solution was to change the second method from `private` to `public`.

Answer (score 0):

According to Pete Muir this is a bug, however, we're not sure if it's fixed or not. Trying a newer version of JBoss (build it from source) will work. If it's still an issue, please create a [bug report](https://issues.jboss.org).

Comment: I created a simple test case that seems to be working now in 7.1.1 as well as 7.2, strange! Trying out the actually failing code in 7.2 will take a little longer time.